# How to trigger programatically the low battery screen

Tags: android, intentfilter

Is there a way to trigger the low battery alert programmatically in Android? Any intent or any other method for this? May be one can change programmatically the battery level that triggers the alert?

I would prefer a method for the non-rooted device but rooted device methods are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

You can always monitor the battery level, state and other things using the API provided by the Android. For more information, you might consider taking a look at this [developer's documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#java).

You need to add the following receiver in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryLevelReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now add a `BroadcastReceiver` class like the following. Name the file as `BatteryLevelReceiver.java`.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BatteryLevelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Show an alert here
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks but I know how to monitor the battery level and I don't need it. What I want is to trigger the low battery alert wiindow